# Is there any Compatibility Test Suite for Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, appcompatactivity

Is there any **Compatibility Test Suite for linux kernel** like we have for **Android** Operating system.
e.g. like when we make changes to the kernel , adding static modules, adding our own programs,configuring kernel and then building.

is there any tool to check that can check compatibility of our kernel.
like is the kernel services like IPC,Memory Memory management,Device Manager will work correct ?
So that could pass/fail/rate the generated kernel.To predict the behavior in the target system.

Comment: Did you see that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177338/how-is-linux-kernel-tested?

Answer (score 0):

You can at least check compatibility of API/ABI of your changed kernel via [abi-dumper](https://github.com/lvc/abi-dumper) and [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.com/abi-compliance-checker/) tools: http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/kernel/

To do this you should add these config options when building your kernel:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED=n
```

And then prepare compatibility report:

```
abi-dumper vmlinux.old -o vmlinux-ABI-0.dump
abi-dumper vmlinux.new -o vmlinux-ABI-1.dump
abi-compliance-checker -l vmlinux -old vmlinux-ABI-0.dump -new vmlinux-ABI-1.dump
```

[image]

EDIT: the project has been moved to http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/timeline/linux/