# Is it feasible to unit test kernel module code ?

Tags: c, module, mocking, kernel

If so what technique should I use ?
I am thinking about using hippomock as they can be used to mock "C" methods. Are there any better approaches ? If so can anyone give an advice, or do you think unit test for kernel is an overkill ?

Comment: Did you do a search on this topic? There are plenty of forum questions around.

Comment: Yes, I did, looks like kernel development do not use any unit tests as such (as it is hard to do so), however I think it can be still done especially with mock frameworks

Comment: Unit testing is really hard to preform to the kernel, the main testing method for the linux-kernel is a huge community performing numerous testing and associated documentation.

Comment: It's certainly not easy, but you may be able to apply [some techniques for testing in embedded programming](https://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c) to kernel modules. It very much depends on how many features of the rest of the kernel your module relies on, as you may need to mock those out, which can become impractical.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177338/how-is-linux-kernel-tested/30367968

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Linux kernel version 5.5 **KUnit** is available. It's a lightweight unit test framework for the kernel.

For more details have a look at

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/kunit/index.html
- https://kunit.dev/
- https://lwn.net/Articles/780985/