# Testing a kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm interested in mocking functions and global variables in order to unit test a kernel module.

Initially tried with https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock but ran into issues. Any articles links on how to do this would also be great. (for kernel modules). To give more details here: compiling as a kernel module would error because stdio wouldn't be available, compiling for user space would error because it wouldn't find stuff like printk.

Ideally I would have either a user level executable or a kernel module that would run unit test on my functions. The parts I am having trouble with is mocking global dependencies like structs that the functions rely on in order to write a decent test.

I've gone through a few [questions](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.kernelnewbies/49915) and [articles](https://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/unit-testing-c-code-with-the-googletest-framework/) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177338/how-is-linux-kernel-tested/30367968) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551498/is-it-feasible-to-unit-test-kernel-module-code) but haven't found an answer, or a definitive reason on why this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would proceed as follows:

- Implement your kernel module
- Define an API to let a user-level program test your module, which can be based either on:

  - a character device in `/dev/` (where you can define proper ioctls);
  - a file in `/proc/` (discouraged);
  - specific system calls (discouraged);
  - an entry in `/sys/`
- Implement at user-level a program (in case, using a proper framework like [CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/) or [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest)), which interacts with the kernel module testing the various functionalities

Comment: I like the idea but it's difficult to put into practice for code that has already been written.