# How are the Linux kernel releases tested

Tags: linux, testing, linux-kernel

I was wondering how the [Linux kernel sources](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) are tested before official release. I am aware of the question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177338/how-is-the-linux-kernel-tested), but I am looking for a very specific answer to the questions, how the kernel is compiled and which tests are run (kselftest?) before they are tagged for a release.

Comment: Better ask Linux kernel developers in their mailing list. I am unsure that someone else know their testing details.

Comment: Oh, that's actually a good idea...when I have an IT related question and need a large user base to ask, SO is the first that comes to my mind. I am probably too young to grow up with mailing lists ;)

Comment: It's a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177338/how-is-the-linux-kernel-tested

Comment: @0andriy: You didn't even read the whole question right...

Comment: You didn't read that link, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the Linux kernel tested ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177338/how-is-the-linux-kernel-tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly linux kernel tested by LTP.

LTP - Linux Test Project

The Linux Test Project is a joint project started by SGI, developed and maintained by IBM, Cisco, Fujitsu, SUSE, Red Hat and others, that has a goal to deliver test suites to the open source community that validate the reliability, robustness, and stability of Linux. The LTP testsuite contains a collection of tools for testing the Linux kernel and related features.

https://linux-test-project.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am aware of the LTP. Are all kernels from kernel.org tested with the LTP before they are released?

Comment: Developer will test their own code before submitting. I am not sure there's a mechanism to centrally collect test cases. Think of a  developer write a code for hardware module, which (HW) is manufactured in their house, so the driver for the chip should be tested  there only.

Comment: Usually SDK's (Linux, Bootloader.. etc) of specific evaluation module is tested using LTP by vendors. SDK will be given by specific vendor (TI, NXP, QUALCOMM). Before releasing to us, they used to test and release it.

Comment: Those were answers I was looking for, thanks @Rajeshkumar